# Debian - microSD lost async page write

Tags: debian, disk, ssd

I face some issue with microSD on a Lenovo S130-14IGM. My laptop is running lastest Debian 9. 
I have a microSD with an ext4 partition located on `/dev/mmcblk1p3` which behave strangely.

When I try to copy /home to it, it's surprisingly fast (it's normal microSD, not an extreme or pro model) :

```
use@server:~$ df -hP /home
/dev/mmcblk0p3      11G    226M   11G   3% /home

use@server:~$ time sudo cp -a /home/ /mnt/backup/home.bak                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
real    0m2,249s                                                                                                                                                         
user    0m0,109s                                                                                                                                                         
sys     0m0,944s
```

Then when I try to deleted it, I does not work.

```
use@server:~$ time sudo rm -rf /mnt/backup/home.bak
```

The command line prompt stay stuck. After a Ctrl+C, it tells me that the device is read protected. 
I cannot remount it in read and write. When I reboot I face this kinds of errors :

```
[    6.375297] mmc1: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[    7.825684] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 88151744
[    7.825795] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 532952, lost async page write
[    7.825927] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 532953, lost async page write
[    7.826035] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 532954, lost async page write
[    7.826142] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 532955, lost async page write
[    7.826248] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 532956, lost async page write
[    7.826353] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 532957, lost async page write
[    7.826458] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 532958, lost async page write
[    7.826563] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 532959, lost async page write
[    7.826672] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 532960, lost async page write
[    7.826779] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 532961, lost async page write
[   11.283705] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

I tried with different microSD, always the same problem. 
Is this a physical problem ? Or and OS related problem ?

**EDIT** : more information :

```
[  101.259951] mmc1: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[  102.762217] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 96471296
[  102.762232] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 1572896, lost async page write
[...]
[  102.762283] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 1572904, lost async page write
[  102.762287] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 1572905, lost async page write
[  102.826584] JBD2: recovery failed
[  102.826595] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p3): error loading journal
[  107.788103] mmc1: card 1234 removed
[  114.171661] mmc1: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[  114.295837] mmc1: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDXC card at address 1234
[  114.297762] mmcblk1: mmc1:1234 SA64G 57.7 GiB
[  114.298854]  mmcblk1: p1 p2 p3
[  118.234255] mmc1: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[  119.713075] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 96471296
[  119.713091] buffer_io_error: 118 callbacks suppressed
[  119.713095] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 1572896, lost async page write
[  119.713120] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 1572897, lost async page write
[...]
[  119.713167] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1p3, logical block 1572905, lost async page write
[  119.772674] JBD2: recovery failed
[  119.772685] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p3): error loading journal
[  125.129966] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  261.588698] mmc1: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[  263.092258] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 42240000
[...]
[  263.402597] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 42243072
[  263.402610] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk1p2): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 10 writing to inode 917598 (offset 0 size 8388608 starting block 5280512)
[...]
[  401.751429] mmc1: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[  403.197791] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 71374080
[  543.585526] EXT4-fs warning: 25 callbacks suppressed

$ lspci | grep -i card
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

I tried this kernel driver without success :  https://github.com/Zibri/Realtek-rts5229-linux-driver

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `/mnt/backup/home.bak` is a folder with write access, this sounds like a physical problem, or corrupted partition table. You should run `fsck`. For backup partition `ddrescue` is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your help !
Yes, /dev/mmcblk1p3 is mounted with default option (in rw). I have partitioned several times the microSD with different start block without success. 
It's not a real backup partition, I'll use it as it but not until this problem is solved. Is there any other test I can do ?

Comment: i guess this microSD is just end of life (wear-out). try badblocks or check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30182 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27619

Comment: I have tried this with 3 or 4 differents SD card (which run perfectly in DSLR, etc) always the same result. I'll try the things you mention.

Comment: have you thought about the card reader may cause this fault?

Answer (score 0):

After research i found out that it may OS related. Do you have SDHC or SDXC cards? There may some incompatiblity with Card Reader. The first error message mmc1: cannot verify signal voltage switch is kernel related. Someone has reported this as bug for Fedora 28. But is unclear to me if it is really a bug or hardware incompatiblity. Do you have the possibility to test the Card Reader with Windows?

Comment: I added some information. I tried to install Windows 10 but failed with error : `no device drivers were found`

Comment: Ok forget windows. Can you try to compile this driver? https://github.com/astyonax/patched-RTS5227-5229