# dd stops working after writing for couple of seconds

Tags: linux, dd

I want to install ubuntu server, so I decided to use `dd`. After executing following command dd writes some bytes there(I think it wrote every byte) and stops.

`sudo dd bs=32M if=ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb conv=fdatasync,fsync status=progress`

this is the output I get:

```
958398464 bytes (958 MB, 914 MiB) copied, 4 s, 236 MB/s
```

I can't do anything here. When I unplug my usb stick it prints out following lines:

```
dd: fdatasync failed for '/dev/sdb': Input/output error
28+1 records in
28+1 records out
958398464 bytes (958 MB, 914 MiB) copied, 84.5967 s, 11.3 MB/s
```

I tried to google, but couldn't find something useful.

**Additional infos**:

- `lsblk` outputs following (when I executed `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb`):

```
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1  14.6G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

- `lsblk` outputs following (after I unplug my USB stick):

```
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1  14.6G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   914M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   1   3.9M  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

- `dmesg` output

```
...
Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 46807, lost async page write
...
[sdb] No Caching mode page found
[sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
...
```

- `iostat` output

```
Linux 5.10.2-2-MANJARO (hrant-80q5)     01/14/21    _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2.46    0.03    2.02   37.11    0.00   58.38

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
sda               6.58       218.68       164.16         0.00    1726719    1296228          0
sdb               0.11         0.24         5.93         0.00       1916      46808          0
sr0               0.00         0.00         0.00         0.00          2          0          0
```

- `iostat /dev/sdb` 1 output

```
.....

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.01    0.00    0.50   73.55    0.00   24.94

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
sdb               0.00         0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0          0


avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           4.20    0.00    2.22   70.12    0.00   23.46

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
sdb               0.00         0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0          0


avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          12.14    0.00    4.85   62.38    0.00   20.63

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
sdb               0.00         0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0          0


avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           7.59    0.00    3.54   66.58    0.00   22.28

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
sdb               0.00         0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0          0


avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           3.51    0.00    2.01   70.93    0.00   23.56

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
sdb               0.00         0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0          0


.....
```

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: I want to get dd working, but it simply freezes.

Comment: What does your `dmesg` output say about that transaction?

Comment: @tink bunch of `Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 20766432, lost async page write`. There are lot of lines, if you want I can update my post and include it.

Comment: My guess is that the write buffer is filled within the 4 seconds and from that point it synchronizes to the USB drive. When you unplug the USB drive IO error occurs because the data can not be written anymore to the device. Let the `dd` command run and in another terminal use `iostat` to see if data is still written to the USB drive.

Comment: I'll hazard a guess and say your memory stick is on its way out ...

Comment: @Lambert see my update.

Comment: Let `iostat` run for a while: `iostat /dev/sdb 1` to see if there is still IO going to the USB drive and don't interrupt `dd`, let it run untill it completes, drops an error or if you don't see any IO for a while using `iostat`

Comment: @tink maybe, idk. However I had same issues months ago where I couldn't simply do anything on Linux. Then I tried the Windows tools and it worked out.

Comment: @Lambert would my output (see updates) mean that `dd` is done and I can unplug my device (because in the 2nd line we have only `0`s)?

Comment: If `dd` is done, it should exit and you should see a new prompt again. When `dd` is still running and looks like it stalls, it's still doing something. In another terminal see if new messages appear in your logs and/or `dmesg` to see if new IO errors occur.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debian - microSD lost async page write](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511194/debian-microsd-lost-async-page-write)

Comment: https://github.com/astyonax/patched-RTS5227-5229